# Can any "Windows Server 2008 R2" or "Silverlight" or "Forefront endpoint" updates affect sharepoint farm

Tags: 2013, administration, sharepoint-on-prem, windows-server, patching

We have windows server 2008 R2 + SharePoint enterprise farm 2013. Now as part of our security policy, we need to install security updates for windows,silverlight & Forefront endpoint each 6 months. Now I checked the Windows Update tool, where I got this list of updates:-

[image]

Now I am planning to install all the updates which are under "**Windows Server 2008 R2**", "**Silverlight**" and "**Forefront Endpoint Protection**". and to **exclude** all the updates under **Office 2013**. So can this affect the sharepoint farm? or cause the farm build number to increase?

Second question, if we only install the "Windows Server 2008 R2", "Silver light" and "Forefront Endpoint Protection", do we need to run the Sharepoint product configuration wizard?

Answer (score 2):

Farm build number will increase only if you will run SharePoint Configuration Wizard after SharePoint cumulative updates(or service pack) installation.

You do not need to run SharePoint Configuration Wizard after installation Windows server updates.

If you will plan to install **.Net security patches** - be careful with this. It may **affect Workflow infrastructure**. [Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2018/09/13/after-installing-net-security-patches-to-address-cve-2018-8421-sharepoint-workflows-stop-working/) to the article.

Comment: thanks for the .Net security  patches warning.. so what i need to do? should i exclude it from the patch ? or should i install it and apply the fix as mentioned on this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2018/09/13/after-installing-net-security-patches-to-address-cve-2018-8421-sharepoint-workflows-stop-working/ ? thanks

Comment: If you plan to use third party workflow tools like Nintex you should add several lines into web.config files. Otherwise you need just install Nov 2018 CU(or later version).

Comment: i am not planning to install any CU in the near future, and in our case we use workflow 2010 inside some lists, we do not use Nintex.. But in all the cases the updates which will cause the issues are not listed inside our WU tool is this correct? the updates which will cause the problems are mainly `KB 4457916/4457035` (as mentioned on this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2018/09/13/after-installing-net-security-patches-to-address-cve-2018-8421-sharepoint-workflows-stop-working/ )which are not listed inside the WU list of updates

Comment: .... and i can see that the only update regarding .net in our case is `KB4054530`

Comment: Hi @JohnJohn , if I answered your question please mark it as an answer.